# Cancel button creating a new account is broken

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts

I pressed the "Ask Question" button on a Stack Exchange site I wasn't part of (Mathematics) and got the "Confirm And Create This Account" screen. However, the "cancel" button did not work.

> [image: Confirm Account]

When I pressed "cancel", the page just reloaded, instead of going back to the page I was on before.

This still continues to be an issue after the new account creation page was redesigned.