# Ask Question > Create new account? > Cancel > Cancel > Cancel > …

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, regression

Apparently, this bug was reported before [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376648/348196) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317430/348196) and it was supposedly [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378952/348196), so it's either a regression or it was just partially fixed (see below).

The bug happens when clicking the "Ask Question" button on (some) sites where you don't have an account, and then clicking on "Cancel" when asked to confirm creating a new account. This leads to an infinite loop of redirecting to the same page over and over.

Notes:

- This happens on some sites but not others (I managed to reproduce on the two sites mentioned below).
- This does *not* happen if you go to the "Confirm your new account" page via the "Join this community" button.
- It doesn't just refresh the page; it redirects to the same URL. So, clicking the "Back" button in your browser will present the same page.

To reproduce:

1. Go to [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) (assuming you don't have an account on one of them).
2. Click "Ask Question".
3. When asked to confirm creating a new account, click "Cancel".

---

Checking the URL of the "Cancel" link shows exactly why this happens. For example, on Mathematics, the URL is `/users/cancel-join?returnUrl=https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`, whereas on other sites, say Academia, it's `/users/cancel-join?returnUrl=https://academia.stackexchange.com`

Comment: It's possible that this bug only affects sites which [require registration to ask questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227111/why-are-unregistered-users-not-allowed-to-post-questions-on-some-sites). I think the earlier bug affected some other functionality and so only fixed it for other sites that don't require registration to ask questions.

Comment: @Sonic Not really. It doesn't seem to affect The Workplace or Politics, for example. Also, I believe that sites that don't require registration to ask questions don't even display that "Confirm your new account" page but rather open the ask page normally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clicking on Cancel just refreshes the page when you are logged in and not have participated in a community and click on Ask a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370907/clicking-on-cancel-just-refreshes-the-page-when-you-are-logged-in-and-not-have-p?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1238011_370907) - probably the comment by @rene is helpful, there's nowhere to take you to because asking a question requires an account.

Comment: @Rob As I mentioned at the very beginning of the question, this is either a regression of the bug that was fixed last May (see the answer to the final dupe target) or something that was overlooked. As to the part about "nowhere to take you to", it should take me back to the homepage because a) that's what happens on many other sites (e.g., Academia, Politics, etc.) and b) it's what that answer to the dupe says is _supposed to happen_.

Comment: To quote from that answer: _"Now when cancelling profile creation, the user will be redirected back to the front-page of the site they were joining. This ensures that users won't land on pages that could redirect them infinitely."_. This expected behavior happens with some sites, but not others. I believe that's a bug that should be addressed.

Comment: Yes, see next comment there.

Comment: @Rob Following the chain of duplicates there, this bug was previously fixed, but has come up again. The team prefers that users file new bug reports if a previously-fixed report comes up again; those are not duplicates.

Comment: @Sonic, I can find only 2 posts that say that, [1 where you spoke on behalf of the staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/316712/revisions) and edited in the declaration. It gains more credibility when you include a link. --- I usually ping on a recent report, and explain that it's reoccurring, that often ensures that it's double checked. --- My bug reports are frequently fixed within a day, it's not about gaining the most rep or reinventing the wheel; the Dev would benefit from the previous reports which probably have a note about where in the code that previous fixes were implemented.

Comment: @Rob [Here's the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207112/could-we-have-a-space-between-these-words-please#comment658713_207112).

Comment: @Rob Unrelated to this topic, but out of curiosity: why do you often suggest closed questions as duplicates when you VTC as dupe? Isn't it better to close as a dupe of questions that are still open? Or does it have to do with allowing others to follow the train of thought, so to speak?

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378952/422926) clearly states it was fixed, so VTLO.

Comment: Solution: don't cancel. ;)

Comment: @Rob It asks the same thing, but the question you suggest is closed as a duplicate of a question that's marked [status-completed] where a staff member said they fixed it. So I'm not sure closing something that can still be reproduced as a duplicate of something that has been fixed is appropriate.

Comment: @DonaldDuck, there's mod deleted comments above; so the subject is resolved / closed.

Comment: I was the one who fixed the reference closed issue back in May. I took a brief look at the changes in that area since and nothing is sticking out to me. My guess would be this is a missed failure condition that exhibits the same behavior.